# `git commit -a` shows that directory has uncommitted changes even after they are added

Tags: git

I have the following tree:

```
Staged:  
foo
foo/a.txt  
foo/b.txt  

Unstaged:  
foo/c.txt
```

If I `git add foo/c.txt` and `git commit -a` I see the following in vi:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   foo/a.txt
#       modified:   foo/b.txt
#       new file:   foo/c.txt
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       foo/
```

I get scared that something might be missing, so I back out of the commit and `git add -A; git commit` and then I see the following in vi:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   foo/a.txt
#       modified:   foo/b.txt
#       new file:   foo/c.txt
```

Which is normal.

**EDIT**

`foo/` is not in my `.gitignore`
`foo/a.txt` and `foo/b.txt` were not originally staged. I just added them with `git commit -a`
`foo/` was not a symlink, file, or another repository

Why does `foo/` show up untracked initially?  I'm just trying to save some keystrokes here.

To complicate matters, this only sometimes reproducible.  I'm running `git version 1.7.7.5 (Apple Git-26)`

**MORE EDIT**

The following commands:

```
git init foo
cd foo
mkdir bar
cd bar
touch 1
touch 2
cd ..
git add -A
git commit
echo 1 >> bar/1
echo 2 >> bar/2
git commit -a
```

Produce the following status in my editor:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   bar/1
#       modified:   bar/2
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       bar/
```

Comment: I'm surprised to see `foo` as staged initially. Was it once a symlink or a file or perhaps another repository?

Comment: Is `foo/` in your `.gitignore` file, and were `a.txt` and `b.txt` added with the `-f` flag?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not actually able to reproduce foo being staged or seeing it as untracked. It seems odd that it would do that since git doesn't track directories, need more info.

Comment: Can you provide a gist ;-) or something with a complete set of steps to reproduce from scratch? Shouldn't be too many from git init .

Comment: I think the clue may be in 'Apple'. This could be a case insensitive file system or some magic Unicode normalization going on.